# Wien bridge oscillator amplitude stability methods

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, oscillator, wien-bridge

I have read things about tungsten bulbs and its thermally controlled resistance. But what can I use for an electronics project will be builded on a breadboard. I searched for tungsten bulbs and all they were looking like regular size 100+ V lamps.

So what is the alternative in electronics level for amplitude stability of wien bridge oscillator?

p.s : don't know relevant or not but, the oscillator will be used in an auido project.

Comment: Search for "filament indicator lamp". I used a 6V 40mA bulb in my Wien bridge oscillator and it worked 'brilliantly'! Much lower distortion than a FET.

Answer (score 3):

Any low-voltage, low-power incandescent bulb can be made to work.  The trouble, in 2019, is finding them -- LED's just work so spectacularly better for making light from battery power, you'll need to dig around to find incandescent bulbs.

If you can find them, get some low-voltage (1.5 or 3V) "grain of wheat" bulbs.

If I were going to make a Wein bridge oscillator for production, I think I'd find an alternative to using a light bulb to set the gain.  I'd probably use a separate amplitude-measuring stage followed by an electronically-variable resistor.  For that I'd start with an analog multiplier, or perhaps a JFET or a switched-capacitor "resistor" operating well above my highest intended frequency.  I might use a CdS photocell with an LED shining on it.

Comment: well first of all thanks, and, last paragraph looks like it needs some care to be taken by me. I will have a look at it, however if it looks like too much work, I might go without any amplitude stability. The job is not that much critical. So let me ask you this, If I don't use any amplitude stability, is the only problem to get sinusoids  somehow distorted/clipped from its top and bottom parts instead of pure nice looking sine waves, or will it lead to another problems?

Comment: I assumed because you were talking about bulbs that you were aiming for super-low distortion.  See figure one of [this app note](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/80206653AN580.pdf).

Comment: Yes, CdS.  I've edited my answer.  I don't know the details of an exemption, but the itty bitty cheap model airplane tachometers still use CdS cells, even though they're inferior to modern cheap phototransistors.

Comment: @DwayneReid can't say I am living somewhere people celebrate christmast :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Search a bit harder. It's not hard to find bulbs such as the 28VDC 1819 which are stocked by distributors such as Digikey (where the photo of the CM1819 came from - 3,500+ in stock).

[image]

Of course you can use other methods (such as a JFET) to do gain control but the lamp + LDR is a time-proven method.

There's generally a trade-off between the time it takes the oscillator to stabilize and the distortion. Here's an example circuit [from TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa665c/snoa665c.pdf) that uses a JFET:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but for a project which will run on a battery lets say 9V, 28V is still too much. Anyway I will check other recommendations of yours, thanks

Comment: There are many other voltages available. The 28V might have a few volts RMS across it in normal operation, not the full rated voltage. #327 bulb is similar, you can check Jim Williams (RIP) AN43 which has some more info on lamps and JFETs.

Comment: are these LF155 and 2N3819 specific to get this circuit work? Can I use another opamp and jfet? For example I have uA741 and  BF246 N channel j fet?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options not mentioned in the other answers that make good alternatives to a filament lamp.

The first is a thermistor. As a lamp is PTC, and the most common thermistor type is NTC, the voltage divider in which it's used has to be flipped around, but otherwise it works just the same. You can get very tiny low power thermistors, with resistances in the 10s or 100s of kohms.

The other is to use gain clipping. Although this gives you a finite amount of distortion, the amplitude response is instant, and with careful design, the distortion can be made to be very small. Arrange your gain stage to have a gain of 3.1 with low signal, and 2.9 with high signal when the diodes conduct, and your distortion will be inaudible to all but the 'golden-eared'.

Comment: Hey, thanks for these ideas. I had also seen that 2 diodes clipping configuration but I was not able to understand why the diodes will not be on? For most of the time the voltage looks like to be enough(>0.7) to enable one diode at each stage.